Find matrix and eigenvalues given eigenvectors
Given the matrix $ \begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
1 & -1 & 4 \\
d & e & f 
\end{bmatrix}  $ and its eigenvectors $ v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
5 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}  $ and $ v_2 = v_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}  $, complete the matrix and find its eigenvalues.
What I have done:

Used the equation $Av_i = \lambda_i v_i$ on each of the eigenvectors. Found that $\lambda_1 = 0$ and $\lambda_2 = -1$, also $b = e = 0$ and $a = -c, d = -f$.
Used the equation $det(A - \lambda I) = 0$ with the information found above to determine that $cd = 0$.
The matrix, when diagonalized, should be $A = PDP^{-1}$ where the columns of $P$ are the eigenvectors. But since there are two identical eigenvectors, $P$ is not invertible. So I cannot plug this formula to find $A$.

Is there anything other property I can use that I'm not seeing?
Context: this is a beginning linear algebra problem. Think of the public as a college-bound senior or a first year undergraduate.

Your first conclusion is fine. So, now you know that $A$ has the form$$\begin{bmatrix}a&0&-a\\1&-1&4\\d&0&-d\end{bmatrix}.$$I don't understand how is it that you got your second conclusion. We have\begin{align}\det(A-\lambda\operatorname{Id})&=-\lambda^3+a\lambda^2-d\lambda^2-\lambda^2+a\lambda-d\lambda\\&=-\lambda(\lambda+1)(\lambda-a+d).\end{align}So, since you know that $-1$ is a double root, you will have to have $-a+d=1$, or $d=a+1$. So,$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a&0&-a\\1&-1&4\\a+1&0&-a-1\end{bmatrix}.$$And then, for any $a$, each of the given conditions is fulfilled.
